# Finding an USB device path

Tags: linux, usb, block-device

Recently I saw this command posted on the internet:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/
```

It worked, but I'm concerned, does it work on other Linux distros? How can I find USB device on the computer where USB is not automatically mounted?

Comment: Not sure I understood the Q correctly, but whether the `lsblk` and `blkid` is what you are looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by "everywhere"? Obviously, it doesn't work on DOS 6.0 or Windows. But it'll work across a wide range of modern Linux distros. Probably not other Unix systems, though.

Comment: Yes, I've meant other Linux distros. I was troubled by the naming of USB storage devices and this command line seems to work on the most of the computers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of the Ubuntu 8.10 system, I use the below approach if my device is not mounted automatically.

Run the `fdisk -l` command.From man page of `fdisk`,

```
 -l     List the partition tables for the  specified  devices  and  then
              exit.   If no devices are given, those mentioned in /proc/parti-
              tions (if that exists) are used.
```

Now, even when my USB is not mounted, the above command will list the USB drive. Now, you can probably create a mount point somewhere in `/media` or wherever you like and manually mount the USB drive as,

```
mount /dev/sda1 /media/usb-drive
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dmesg just after plugging the USB device to figure out how kernel handles the device and where you can find it.